# How to unpack a wrapper JSON object that has a dynamic name

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I am currently working against an api that returns all values wrapped inside a standard data object with a dynamic name, or so:

```
{
   "<this string changes based on call>: {
      "code": 0,
      "message: "msg",
      "<this parameter name changes based on call>": T
   }
}
```

I have figured out a way to use Retrofit's Converter.Factory to handle the object it self, and return the data payload correctly. However handling the dynamic name of the object, and extracting the underlying object, is proving to be more of a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the JSON object to be a HashMap.
And loop through the keys of the HashMap.

In this case, the HashMap would be of type 
`HashMap<String, Object>`.

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting, but that would not solve the problem.